# API data Angular 5

Tags: json, angular, postman

Hi there I trying to access the 'flightAware' API's data. I have made a get request on Postman and it returns all the data about the flight perfectly.

When I try it in my angular application I get the error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

code:

```
constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getSites(): Observable<ISearchResponse> {
    return this._http.get<ISearchResponse>(this._siteURL)
      .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log('SearchEngineService: ' + err.message);
    return Observable.throw(err.message);
  }
}
```

ISearchResponse

```
interface ISearchResponse {

  airports: IItem[];

}
```

IItem

```
interface IItem {
    name:string;
}
```

Postman Results:

```
 "airports": [
            {
                "fs": "JFK",
                "iata": "JFK",
                "icao": "KJFK",
                "faa": "JFK",
                "name": "John F. Kennedy International Airport",
                "street1": "JFK Airport",
                "city": "New York",
                "cityCode": "NYC",
                "stateCode": "NY",
                "postalCode": "11430",
                "countryCode": "US",
                "countryName": "United States",
                "regionName": "North America",
                "timeZoneRegionName": "America/New_York",
                "weatherZone": "NYZ178",
                "localTime": "2017-11-17T09:37:34.462",
                "utcOffsetHours": -5,
                "latitude": 40.642335,
                "longitude": -73.78817,
                "elevationFeet": 13,
                "classification": 1,
                "active": true,
                "delayIndexUrl": "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/delayindex/rest/v1/json/airports/JFK?codeType=fs",
                "weatherUrl": "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/weather/rest/v1/json/all/JFK?codeType=fs"
            }
```

Comment: looks more like a CORS issue to me

Comment: @RahulSingh I was thinking that myself. Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: you need to add Corss origin support to the server that sends data , if it is your local you can make it yourself else you might need to ask the developer of this api

Comment: @RahulSingh thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solution: Download chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en and activate

Comment: That's what I did forgot to post about it tho! thanks